# creating a list of objects

Tags: vba

Hi can I use a variable to create an object.
I have an array of several names and for each of those names, I would like to create an object. 
So I have `("Max", "Tim", "Fred")`
and would like to loop through that array with the result that I get something similar to doing it manual like this

```
Dim Max as CmyClass
Dim Tim as CmyClass
Dim Fred as CmyClass
```

(if that is very much against all good habits of programming, please let me know how to do that properly)

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do with the array. Can you be more specific?

Comment: This is a good use for Scripting.Dictionary, as long as your "names" are all unique

Answer (score 7):

It's not against good programming for as far as I know, but you would need something to store the objects in, which in the case of VBA would be an array or a collection.

something like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As Collection

    Set col = New Collection

    For i = 0 To 4
        Dim Name As Class1
        Set Name = New Class1
        col.Add Name, "test" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answers. will try to get this implemented today

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim d As Object
    Dim o As CmyClass
    Dim arr, k, x

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    arr = Array("Max", "Tim", "Fred")

    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
       Set o = New CmyClass
       'set o properties etc
       o.Name = "Name is " & arr(x)
       d.Add arr(x), o
    Next x


    For Each k In d.keys
       Debug.Print k, d(k).Name
    Next k

End Sub
```